# Select values based on the values of the first column

Tags: vba, select, key-value, multiple-columns

I have a database that looks something like this:

```
Name    -Finding One    -Finding Two    -Finding Three

John    -Low Cost       
John    -Accessible     -Low Cost   
Michael -High Cost      -Good Quality   -Good CSR

Michael -Low Cost       -Friendly CSR   
Michael -Average Cost       
Michael -Lot of Features    -Good Quality   
Charles -Average Cost       
Bryan   -High Cost      -Friendly CSR
```

As we can see, we have the same guy working different accounts and reporting on their findings.

I need to get the findings per worker and put them in different columns, so that I can remove the duplicate values (for example, John found "Low Cost" in 2 different accounts - I only need it listed once). And, once I've removed the duplicates, I need to put the remaining in one cell (as a string of text) - per installer (not the overall conglomerate).

Please help. I'm so new in VBA.

Note on the side: I started separating the installers with a macro (thinking that leaving a space in between the installers would help to work out the rest - I've worked with little success in finding a solution to this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for ?

```
Sub sample()


    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A2:B" & lastRow).Copy Range("F1")
    Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Copy Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Copy Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

    Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Copy Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Range("D2:D" & lastRow).Copy Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)


    lastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F1:G" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that you answered my question... and in a quite succinct way.